# Retraction to an interval in a metric space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Suppose that $X$ is a metric space and $A$ is a subspace of $X$ that is homeomorphic to the interval $[0,1]$ with its usual topology. Let $v$ and end point of A. How do you proof that there is a retraction $r$ from $X$ onto $A$ such that $r^{-1}(v)=\{v\}$.

Thanks

Comment: What is an 'end point' of $A$?

Comment: @copper.hat A point that does not disconnect A. Recall that A is homeomorphic to [0,1]. The end point of A are the equivalents to 0 and 1 in the interval.

Comment: Let $h$ be the homeomorphism, and suppose $h(v)=0$ (otherwise consider $h'(x) = 1-h(x)$), then let $\phi(x) = h^{-1}(\max(1,d(x,v)))$ (see @CareBear's remark).

Comment: @copper.hat maybe you mean the min? Is h defined from A into the interval [0,d(v,w)] where w is the other end point?

Comment: Sorry, my browser was messed up and I was unable to delete my comment, which is incorrect. The $\phi$ I gave is not a retract, it does not fix elements of $A$.

Comment: @CareBear I do not see how is that easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h:A\to[0,1]$ be a homeomorphism such that $h(v)=1$. By the Tietze extension theorem there is a continuous $H:X\to[0,1]$ such that $H\upharpoonright A=h$. $X$ is metrizable, so there is a continuous $g:X\to[0,1]$ such that $A=g^{-1}[\{1\}]$; let

$$f:X\to[0,1]:x\mapsto H(x)g(x)\;;$$

clearly $f$ is continuous, $f\upharpoonright A=h$, and $f(x)=1$ iff $x=v$. Then $r=h^{-1}\circ f$ is the desired retraction.

One can also hit this with a very big hammer: it’s an old result of Hausdorff that if $X$ is metrizable, $A$ is a closed subset of $X$, and $d$ is a metric on $A$ that generates the topology that $A$ inherits from $X$, then there is a metric $\rho$ on $X$ that extends $d$ and generates the topology of $X$. Here we can take $d(x,y)=|h(x)-h(y)|$ for $x,y\in A$, extend $d$ to $\rho$, and let $r(x)=\rho(v,x)$ to get the desired retraction.